# How to remove materialLayer in UIController?

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

This line of code adds materialLayer to view layer.

```
view.layer.addSublayer(materialLayer)
```

How to remove it from UIView?

Comment: `materialLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()` ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @jtbandes is correct.

`materialLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()`